# How do I add to the App self-name Menu Item?

Tags: maui, mac-catalyst

Maui easily allows adding menu items, but I can't figure out how to add a Preferences menu under the app menu. For example, Visual Studio Mac has Preferences, as other apps do, on a self-titled MenuItem:

[image: Visual Studio Mac - Menu]

By default, my ContentPage MenuBarItems collection starts empty, and AppShell doesn't even have one.  If I add a self-titled MenuBarItem...

```
 InitializeComponent();
 MessageBox.Owner = this;
 MenuBarItem main = new MenuBarItem();
 // Using AppInfo.Current.Name does not pick up the correct name from the csproj projectName entry.
 main.Text = "Timeliner";
 this.MenuBarItems.Add(main);
```

I get:

[image: App with dual app-named menu items]

So... duplicates.  How can I append to the one-true App MenuItem?  (Same question would go for File, e.g.)

Comment: I've tested on the newest VS, the [MenuBarItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar?view=net-maui-7.0#create-menu-bar-items) does not work on `MacCatalyst`, you may open an [issue report](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=t%2Fbug&template=bug-report.yml) on Github.

Comment: The Preferences/Settings menu automatically appears in a Mac Catalyst app if your app includes a Settings.bundle.